# Unable to manage single elements in an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I am inserting a class object into an NSMutable array, and then I am trying to manage the specific properties of each indexed object.

Here I create the NsMutableArray:

```
    self.currentPuzzle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i = 0; i < [temp length]; i++){     //temp is a string containing #'s and dots.

    AnswerSpecifier *objectToGetIntoArray = [[AnswerSpecifier alloc]init];
    objectToGetIntoArray.value = [[temp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] intValue];

    [self.currentPuzzle addObject:objectToGetIntoArray];
}
```

and here I am trying to change the value property of each object. value is an int property.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.board.boardString length]; i++) {
    [self.currentPuzzle objectAtIndex:i].value = [[self.board.boardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] intValue];

}
```

However I get an error saying that the property value was not found on object of type id. Should I just create a new array and assign it to the old one? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your code up. This makes it easier to read and debug.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.board.boardString length]; i++) {
    AnswerSpecifier *answer = self.currentPuzzle[i];
    NSString *boardString = [self.board.boardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    int value = [boardString intValue];
    answer.value = value;
}
```

You don't get points for cramming as much code as possible into one line.

But if you really just want to fix the one line you need to put the cast in the proper place:

```
[(AnswerSpecifier *)self.currentPuzzle[i] setValue:[[self.board.boardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] intValue]];
```

Comment: Splitting the code cleared a lot of things up. As a curiosity on the one line version, why does the method setValue work if I never declared it? Is that my property value's setter?

Comment: Yes, `setValue:` is the property's setter. `answer.value = xxx` and `[answer setValue:xxx]` are the exact same code.

Answer (score 1):

Try type casting the object

```
((AnswerSpecifier *)[self.currentPuzzle objectAtIndex:i]).value = [[self.board.boardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.board.boardString length]; i++) {
    [[self.currentPuzzle objectAtIndex:i] setValue:[[self.board.boardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] intValue]];

}
```